# Emacsclient: searching for program: no such file or directory, ruby

Tags: emacs, configuration

When I load, with *emacsclient*, a ruby script I see this message: `searching for program: no such file or directory, ruby`. I haven't no problem when I open a script whit *emacs* .Actually, I'm using `enh-ruby-mode` and emacs26. Anybody knows where is the problem?

This is my configuration: https://github.com/sirion1987/emacs.d.

Thank you.

**Update**

I solved by installing `exec-path-from-shell` and adding this snippet:

`(setq exec-path-from-shell-variables '("PATH"))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)`

Comment: what OS, how ruby is installed?

Comment: I have ububtu 16.04 and i use rbenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your emacs is started before the `PATH` is fully setup.  You need to set the `PATH` accordingly.  For that there is a package called [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

I'm personally using [following code](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/.emacs#L4) that is doing the same:

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  (let ((path-from-shell (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -c 'echo $PATH'")))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))
(when window-system (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH))
```

Comment: This snippet it's valid for emacs-nox? Thank you. (I run emacs whit this snippet, but doesn't still work).

Comment: No, I use it only when I run GUI program (it's invoked `(when window-system ...)`). You can try to use mentioned package, or try to execute the function like this: `M-: (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH)` and check that path is adjusted

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip.